# Bitcoin new receive addresses

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash, ecash

With the Bitcoin-ABC cli I can generate as many receive addresses by the following command

```
./bitcoin-cli getnewaddress "label"
```

But from my understanding the funds still go into the same wallet and if I send coins from the wallet it would always be from the same "from" address. Am I correct in my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

> Funds still go into the same wallet and
>   if I send coins from the wallet it would always be from the same
>   "from" address. Am I correct?

Not exactly. It depends on the amount of coins you'll send. Here is an example:

- You have address `A` with `1 BTC`.
- Address `B` with `0.3 BTC`.

Consider you want to send `1.1 BTC` to the address `C`.

In that case the transaction would have *2(A,B) outputs and 2(C, X) inputs* *:

- Outputs: `A` with `1 btc` and `B` with `0.3 BTC`.
- Inputs: `1 BTC` to the address `C` and `0.1 BTC` to the address `C`.
- `0.2 BTC` *will be your change*, and it'll be sended back to you*.

The `from` address will be the collection of your *income* addresses(`A`,`B`, e.t.c.).

*<sub>Some wallets do let you manually select which address should receive the change from a transaction.</sub>

*<sub>In some cases client will create a new address for change.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Actually, wallet just represents the overall amount of bitcoin you have for all the address you generated (It like a database of your bitcoin address), so yes it going to the same wallet.

For address, yes when you send the bitcoin out, your wallet will find the address that has enough funds to send it out (unless u specify which address) which may cause multiple addresses to send to 1 address.

So basically the bitcoin value is stored on the individual address that was used to receive while a wallet just a thing that used to manage those address.

Hopefully this answers your question as I have little trouble understanding it